# Using react hooks how can a user navigates to protected routes based on admin access

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Using `protected.route` when a user login how can we make a user navigates to private routes like `Dashboard` and `ViewDetails` ? If he is an admin user, then display Dashboard, else ViewDetails screen. Can someone please advise on this. I have added a codesandbox link for reference
Codesandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-cerf-kss82?file=/src/components/Login.js

`login.js`

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const loginData = [
  { id: 1, email: "mat@test.com", password: "admin123", access: "admin" },
  { id: 1, email: "duo@test.com", password: "test123", access: "user" }
];
const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();

  const onSubmit = (email, password) => {
    if (
      email === loginData[0].email &&
      password === loginData[0].password &&
      loginData[0].access === "admin"
    ) {
      history.push("/");
    } else {
      history.push("/ViewDetails");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Login Page <br></br>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="email"
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="password"
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input type="button" value="submit" onClick={onSubmit(email, password)} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

`protected.route.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (localStorage.getItem("loginEmail")) {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
          return (
            <>
              <Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: "/login",
                  state: {
                    from: props.location
                  }
                }}
              />
            </>
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

`App.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard.js";
import Login from "./components/Login.js";
import ViewDetails from "./components/ViewDetails.js";
import UserLoginProvider from "./components/UserLoginProvider.js";
import UserProfileProvider from "./components/UserProfileProvider.js";
import ProtectedRoute from "./components/protected.route.js";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
//var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <UserLoginProvider>
        <UserProfileProvider>
          <>
            <Switch>
              <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
              <ProtectedRoute path="/ViewDetails" component={ViewDetails} />
              <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
            </Switch>
          </>
        </UserProfileProvider>
      </UserLoginProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(App, null),
  document.getElementById("root")
);

export default App;
```

Comment: Your `ProtectedRoute` component doesn't appear to take any roles into consideration when it comes to protected access. I also don't see anything that sets anything into localStorage by a `loginEmail` key. In the `Login` component you *do* set a `access` key into localStorage. I also see that you don't utilize the referrer "from" route state to redirect user back to what they were trying to access. Are you just wanting to redirect "admin" roles to "/" and everyone else to "/viewDetails"? It's a bit unclear what your goal is here.

Comment: Yes when a user with "admin" access logs in, it should redirect to `/` Dashboard and other users with "user" access should redirect to /ViewDetails . Sorry I am not sure , how to setup that properly in codesandbox link

Comment: When I refer to one of your answer for some other question.. I was not sure if I need to create `Routes.js` component in my project...

Comment: Where do you want to store your user objects? It looks like you haven't decided between storing it in localStorage or in either of those React Contexts.

Comment: I am happy if its stored in `localStorage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example suggestion.

Update the `ProtectedRoute` component to take an access `role` prop and conditionally render a `Route` or `Redirect` based on any `role` stored in localStorage. If the role matches, return the expected route, if it exists and doesn't match then redirect home, otherwise redirect to login.

```
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ role, ...rest }) => {
  const currentRole = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("role"));
  if (currentRole === role) {
    return <Route {...rest} />;
  } else {
    return (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: currentRole ? "/" : "/login",
          state: {
            from: rest.location
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  }
};
```

Update `Login` to handle saving an authenticated user's `access` role into local storage and redirect back to the path they were originally attempting to access.

```
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { state } = useLocation();

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const onSubmit = (email, password) => {
    const user = loginData.find(
      (el) => el.email === email && el.password === password
    );

    if (user) {
      localStorage.setItem("role", JSON.stringify(user.access));
      history.replace(state.from ?? "/");
    } else {
      console.error("no user match found!");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      ....
    </div>
  );
};
```

Update the protected routes you are rendering in your `App`.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <UserLoginProvider>
      <UserProfileProvider>
        <Switch>
          <ProtectedRoute
            role="admin"
            path="/dashboard"
            component={Dashboard}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            role="user"
            path="/viewDetails"
            component={ViewDetails}
          />
          <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
          <Route>
            .... home page with nav links, etc...
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </UserProfileProvider>
    </UserLoginProvider>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit using-react-hooks-how-can-a-user-navigates-to-protected-routes-based-on-admin-ac]

Comment: Awesome explanation mate ! If I got a chance I could have upvoted multiple times.. you are my saver ! Please publish some simple react tutorials, I will buy it